# Можно ли в параметрах teamcity задавать список запускаемых тестов?

Tags: teamcity

Имеются тесты, которые гоняются в teamcity и выбираются из xml файла, следующего вида:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Validation" parallel="tests" thread-count="4">

<!--Test1-->

<test name="Incorrect.Test1">
    <classes>
        <class name="validation.incorrect.test1"/>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="Incorrect.Test2">
    <classes>
        <class name="validation.incorrect.test2"/>
    </classes>
</test>

<!--Test2-->

<test name="Incorrect.Test3">
    <classes>
        <class name="validation.incorrect.test3"/>
    </classes>
</test>

<!--Test3-->

<test name="Incorrect.Test4">
    <classes>
        <class name="validation.incorrect.test4"/>
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="Incorrect.Test5">
    <classes>
        <class name="validation.incorrect.test5"/>
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

Можно ли как-то в teamcity создать параметры для выбора какой именно тест запускать? Если, например, нет необходимости гонять все тесты из файла.

UPD: Вычитал, что можно задавать фильтрацию в

```
<property></property>
```

в pom.xml.
Это немного проще чем каждый раз редактировать файл со suite-ами, хотелось бы примерно такую же фильтрацию, но с помощью параметров в самом teamcity и с возможностью выбирать не только отдельные тесты но и сьюты целиком.

Answer (score 0):

можно в параметрах через строку или через selector позволять выбирать какие тесты запускать.

в параметрах создаем переменную с типом select  и туда прописываем нужные нам тесты, которые нужно запускать. (параметр по умолчанию - all)

```
all => *Test
test1 => validation.incorrect.test1
test2 => validation.incorrect.test2
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
далее в steps добавляем нашу переменную, которая указывает на список тестов.

```
-Dtest=%tests% test
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При запуске по умолчанию будут все тесты запускаться, а если хотите какой-то отдельный, то в параметрах выбираем нужные чекбоксы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]